# Google Play - unable to deactivate older APK with lower API support

Tags: android, google-play

Background:

I have an app which supported API 10+ before. In recent upgrade, we only support API 11+. So when I upload the new APK, Google Play actually keep both APK published (those who are running API 10 will get the old version of the app). At beginning, I wanted to hold the API 10+ version for a while, so it didn't bother me. But now I have trouble...

[image: Production Configuration on Google Play]

From image above, there is no Deactivate button for me to remove the older version (109). How can I get rid of it from production?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to staged rollout. After full release (100% rollout), I'm able to deactivate the older build now.